# Stored procedure to drop the column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created many tables and I have noticed that I have created one useless column in all the tables. I want to create a stored procedure which will drop one specific column and can be useful in all the column.

I created this stored procedure but I'm getting an error. Help me please

[image: Selected part is store procedure]

Comment: Can I do same task in function or not? If not can you suggest me easy task to do it!

Comment: No - a function **cannot** modify the structure of the SQL Server database

Answer (score 0):

You cannot parametrize table and column names with parameters - those are only valid for **values** - not for object names.

If this is a one-time operation, the simplest option would be to generate the `ALTER TABLE ... DROP COLUMN ...` statements in SSMS using this code:

```
SELECT
    'ALTER TABLE ' + SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id) + '.' + t.Name +
        ' DROP COLUMN Phone;'
FROM
    sys.tables t
```

and then execute this code in SSMS; the output from it is a list of statement which you can then copy & paste to a new SSMS window and execute.

If you really want to do this as a stored procedure, you can apply the same basic idea - and then just use code (a cursor) to iterate over the commands being generated, and executing them - something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.DropColumnFromAllTables (@ColumnName NVARCHAR(100))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SchemaName sysname, @TableName sysname

    -- define cursor over all tables which contain this column in question
    DECLARE DropCursor CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD
    FOR
        SELECT
            SchemaName = s.Name,
            TableName = t.Name
        FROM 
            sys.tables t 
        INNER JOIN 
            sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
        WHERE
            EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.columns c
                    WHERE c.object_id = t.object_id
                      AND c.Name = @ColumnName);

    -- open cursor and start iterating over the tables found
    OPEN DropCursor

    FETCH NEXT FROM DropCursor INTO @SchemaName, @TableName

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @Stmt NVARCHAR(1000)

        -- generate the SQL statement
        SET @Stmt = N'ALTER TABLE [' + @SchemaName + '].[' + @TableName + '] DROP COLUMN [' + @ColumnName + ']';

        -- execute that SQL statement
        EXEC sp_executeSql @Stmt

        FETCH NEXT FROM DropCursor INTO @SchemaName, @TableName
    END

    CLOSE DropCursor
    DEALLOCATE DropCursor
END
```

Answer (score 0):

This procedure should work.

It loops through all cols and then deletes the column where sum(col) is zero.

Take a Backup of the Table

```
alter procedure deletecolumnsifzero @tablename varchar(1000)
as

set nocount on

declare @n int
declare @sql nvarchar(1000)
declare @sum_cols nvarchar(1000)
declare @c_id nvarchar(100)

set @n = 0

declare c1 cursor for
select column_name from information_schema.columns
where
table_name like @tablename

--Cursor Starts
open c1

fetch next from c1
into @c_id

while @@fetch_status = 0

begin

set @sql=''
set @sql='select @sum_cols = sum('+@c_id+') from ['+@tablename+']'
exec sp_Executesql @sql,N'@sum_cols int out,@tablename nvarchar(100)',@sum_cols out,@tablename


if(@sum_cols = 0)

begin

set @n=@n+1
set @sql=''
set @sql= @sql+'alter table ['+@tablename+'] drop column ['+@c_id+']'
exec sp_executesql @sql

end

fetch next from c1
into @c_id

end

close c1
deallocate c1
```